# How to create an alias with 2 values in In the Windows Powershell (profile)

Tags: powershell

I want to create an alias with 2 values in my Windows Powershell profile.

This works fine:
`Set-Alias -Name "gs" -Value "git"`

This throws an expected error
`Set-Alias -Name "gs" -Value git status`

And within quotes
`Set-Alias -Name "gs" -Value 'git status'`

> gs: The term 'git status' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Causes an unexpected error, and I wonder how to formulate the alias definition to let the latter one work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-Alias doesn't natively let you do that, it only allows you to add aliases for individual commands/functions etc... however using a function you can work around that as :

```
Function gitFunction { git status }
Set-Alias -Name "gs" -Value gitFunction
```

so, within the function {} you can have whatever commands etc you want to string together that you'd like, and then you create the alias as a shortcut to the function itself rather than the commands